# bootstrap feedback glyphicons showing on load

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Why are my feedback glyphicons showing up when the page is loaded?

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/dRtZUoDP0xUwhI3SWVrV?p=preview

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success has-feedback' : infoForm.cardExpMonth.$valid }">
      <label class="control-label">Expiration Month</label>
      <div class="right-inner-addon">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newCard.expirationMonth" required cc-exp-month name="cardExpMonth" placeholder="MM" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success has-feedback' : infoForm.cardExpYear.$valid }">
      <label class="control-label">Expiration Year</label>
      <div class="right-inner-addon">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newCard.expirationYear" required cc-exp-year name="cardExpYear" placeholder="YY" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are talking about check mark in input boxes?

Comment: yes, i only want it to show up when the field is valid @Leothelion

Comment: you have to use jquery for this.. see here http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: but there are bootstrap validation states.  when i put in '12' in the month field, it turns to a green checkmark.  im just not sure why the checkmark shows up on load

Comment: The checkmark turned green because its container div has the `has-success`, which is a bootstrap class but provided by Angular condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick workaround using `ng-show` on the icons, would this be good enough?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success has-feedback' : infoForm.cardExpMonth.$valid }">
      <label class="control-label">Expiration Month</label>
      <div class="right-inner-addon">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newCard.expirationMonth" required cc-exp-month name="cardExpMonth" placeholder="MM" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="infoForm.cardExpMonth.$valid" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success has-feedback' : infoForm.cardExpYear.$valid }">
      <label class="control-label">Expiration Year</label>
      <div class="right-inner-addon">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="newCard.expirationYear" required cc-exp-year name="cardExpYear" placeholder="YY" />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" ng-show="infoForm.cardExpYear.$valid" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kTTzbWX3DlZw5k7u1zOT?p=preview

Comment: That works!  I added another field but am wondering why it doesn't need the ng-show. Use 4242424242424242 for the field.  http://plnkr.co/edit/zPM1GpchtrdFCHQMXrwy?p=preview

Comment: It's there. It's pushed above the input, hidden under plunker's controls.

Comment: aaaah, got it.  so basically i will need ng-show anytime i need to do an angular condition?

Comment: Hm.... since the checkmark being shown is bootstrap's default settings, this is the only way I can think of to do it without touching bootstrap's css.